# Goland IDE не видит компилятор golang

Tags: golang, goland

Всегда ставил Go по инструкции с официального сайта в 3 шага:

1. Скачал
2. Распаковал
3. Прописал пути

Но теперь поставил 1.17 вместо 1.16 и Goland не подхватывает её.

> The selected directory is not a valid home for Go SDK.

Если скачать с помощью IDE, то он её кладёт в ~/go, после чего не работают watchers: fmt + imports.

Comment: хоть какие-то настройки можете показать? это точно не проблема Goland

Answer (score 0):

Удалите полностью и даже реестр подчистите. Что то осталось при удалении наверное. И заново поставьте все по инструкции. Как чистить реестр. Можно использовать разные клинеры реестров.

Answer (score 0):

Любые действия:

- Переустановка той же версии
- Изменение месторасположения компилятора
- Скачивание компилятора с помощью IDE

все они не приводят к результату. Единственный способ -- обновиться до последней версии и зарегистрироваться через почту в системе JetBrains. Похоже, что таким образом происходит перевод пользователей на последние версии.